# How do I get up the slippery slope between the two ridged walls in Bogano?

Tags: star-wars-jedi-fallen-order

In the Subterranean area of Bogano, your character learns how to wall run pretty much right next to a massive slope that you can't run up that is nestled in between two really tall walls that are ridged.

[image: Looking up the slope]

Presumably, you're supposed to use wall run to jump between the walls to reach the top before you contact the slope, which once you do, causes you to slide down it back to the bottom. However, I run out of wall to run and reach the slope before reaching the top. Am I not jumping quickly enough from wall to wall? Am I missing a needed skill? Is this even doable so early in the game? The map isn't indicating the area is inaccessible (ie: there's no red markings on the map), so I'm inclined to think there's a trick to this that I'm just missing... or the map isn't being truthful.

Comment: I left because I didn’t even think you were supposed to go up there. So now I’m interested…

Comment: @Fatalize It sounds like there's a force echo up there or something.

Comment: In addition to what is at the top of the ramp, once you are at the top and looking down at the ramp, wall jump again repeatedly and there will be vines for you to swing on and it will bring you to another collectible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not doable early in the game. Later on in the game you unlock a double jump skill, you use the same method of jumping quickly from wall to wall but double jump each time to gain more height.

Comment: I failed to recognize this was a thing in the early game, so I cant confirm or deny if it isnt doable. I did return later in the game with double jump and was able to complete this.

Comment: I also now hear it is possible to do with force pull. In some of my attempts, I've ended up wall jumping in the opposite direction after hitting the slope. At the top of the open room, there's a rope hanging down. It sounds like you can force pull the rope to yourself, and then swing up to the top of the slope. But, I haven't had a chance to play in a while so haven't been able to confirm all of this stuff.